# Suspected Installshield Sequencing Issue

Tags: installshield

First I'd like to thank all the contributors to stack overflow, I've learned so much and been helped through countless school projects and cases at work using your examples and advise.

Unfortunately I've encountered a problem I haven't been able to solve through research and testing.

I'm working with installshield and building patch installer msi's for client patchs. The issue I'm experiencing is when you open the new patch installer msi  with the updated patch number and cancel the install of the download on the first dialogue screen before ever actually beginning the download, the software receiving the patch is being falsely updated with the patch number (found in the help 》about area of the software) even though the install was cancelled, acting as though it has received the patch updates (the actual code updates are not being installed tho).

I'm trying to figure out why it's updating the softwares patch number and from there how to stop it from updating the patch number when the install is cancelled. I'm pretty sure this is a sequencing issue within installshield, but I'm just really having trouble figuring out where to start. It feels like I've tried everything.I hope my explanation isn't too broad. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I think your question is a little too vague. Please try providing as much detail as possible. More detail will allow contributors to provide better answers :).

Comment: Thanks Stratus for the advice. I updated my question and tried to make my situation clearer. Do you have any experience with installshield?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like an InstallShield problem, though you can't rule it out. The key question is about where the app gets that Help->About value from. It doesn't seem like a sequencing problem because the UI should in all cases perform no changes to the system. It's possible that a custom action is running that sets the version value in the UI sequence before you even see the dialog, and that won't be backed out unless it's backed out when Cancel is pushed. If that's the case then the design of the setup is incorrect. So if there is a custom action that (for example) writes to the registry in the UI sequence (and the program picks up the value from there) then the design is incorrect. That CA must be moved to the execute sequence, and have a rollback CA to undo it if the patch install fails. A verbose log of the patch install may tell you what's going on - look for custom actions and anything suspicious happening before that dialog is shown.